# Unable to recreate custom segment in python using the Google Analytics Reporting API

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In Google Analytics, I have a custom segment that is supposed to exclude sessions from a specific country and exclude sessions on pages that start with a certain word (e.g.: /gallery)  in the page path.
Here is what the custom segment looks like:
Country: not match regex "(France)" &
Sessions exclude Page contains "/gallery"

I am trying to recreate this in python using the Google Analytics Reporting API, but seem unable to recreate the condition Sessions exclude Page contains "/gallery".

Here is what I have written:

```
'segments':  [
    {
        'dynamicSegment':
            {
                'name': 'Custom Segment 1',
                'sessionSegment':
                    {
                        'segmentFilters': [
                            {
                                'simpleSegment':
                                    {
                                        'orFiltersForSegment': [
                                            {
                                                'segmentFilterClauses': [
                                                    {
                                                        'not': True,
                                                        'dimensionFilter':
                                                            {
                                                                'dimensionName': 'ga:country',
                                                                'operator': 'REGEXP',
                                                                'expressions': ['France']
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                                },
                                            {
                                                'segmentFilterClauses': [
                                                    {
                                                        'not': True,
                                                        'dimensionFilter':
                                                            {
                                                                'dimensionName': 'ga:pagePath',
                                                                'operator': 'BEGINS_WITH',
                                                                'expressions': ['/gallery']
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                                }]
                                    }
                            }]
                    }
            }
    }]
```

However, from my understanding, this creates a segment like the following: Country: not match regex "(France)" & Sessions include Page does not contains "/gallery"

How can I recreate Sessions exclude Page contains "/gallery" in my code? I can recreate "Include does not contain x" but not "Exclude contains x", and I want to do the latter. I've tried looking online and [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet) but still don't understand.

Comment: Does anybody have an idea?